# Is there a character that looks like a 5 with a line through it like $?

Tags: unicode, character

Does there exist a character in unicode (or possibly some other standard) that looks like a 5 with a line through it vertically, similar to the $ character?

Comment: $ is `U+0024` in unicode

Comment: There are thousands of unicode characters: http://unicode-table.com/en/#devanagari.  I'm not familiar like what you mention though.  What do you need it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct it yourself using [combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). Combine the 5 (Unicode position 53/0x35) with the  ⃒ character to receive 5⃒.

HTML example:

```
&#53;&#8402;
```

A generally helpful resource for finding Unicode characters (although it does not support the vast amount of asian characters) try [shapecatcher.com](http://shapecatcher.com/).

Comment: That's awesome. I didn't even know you could do that with unicode. Thank you so much!